# Toggle each table row until a table row with X class is reached

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I'm integrating an accordion effect into a table.

The table rows with the class 'more' are children of the above table row. When that table row is clicked, I want the 'more' tr's to toggle. How do I just target those table rows and not the regular 'row' table rows.

```
        <tr class="row first">
            <td>
                <span class="time">09.00&ndash;09.15</span>
                <h3>
                    Welcome and introduction</h3>
            </td>
            <td>
                person info</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row">
            <td>
                <span class="time">09.00&ndash;09.15</span>
                <h3>
                    Welcome and introduction</h3>
            </td>
            <td>
                person info</td>
        </tr>


        <tr class="more">
            <td>
                <h3>
                    hidden content</h3>
            </td>
            <td>
                person info</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="more">
            <td>
                <h3>
                    hidden info</h3>
            </td>
            <td>
                person info</td>
        </tr>
            </div>

        <tr class="row">
            <td>
                <span class="time">09.00&ndash;09.15</span>
                <h3>
                    Welcome and introduction</h3>
            </td>
            <td>
                person info</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row break">
            <td>
                <h3>
                    10.50&ndash;11.20 Coffee break</h3>
            </td>
            <td>
                &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you've got so far? [What have you tired](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)?

Comment: Notice that if you hide the `more` rows then how are you going to click on them?

Comment: The .more rows are hidden by default. Clicking the parent will open them. (the parent being the TR above the .more tr's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a combination of [`.nextUntil()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) and `:not`.

```
$("table tr.row").each(function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.click(function(){
    $this.nextUntil(":not(.more)").toggle();
  });
});
```

The selector `:not(.more)` matches all the elements that doesn't contain a `more` classname.

[See it here.](http://jsfiddle.net/pMtLb/)

Comment: That worked a treat. Never knew nextUntil existed so thanks for that.